# Filling missing values of a pandas dataframe with growth rates of another by group

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill missing values of series 'X', by growing it backwards using series 'Y' (assuming it is a percentage growth rate). I am trying do this by group 'G'. When I debug, I can see that my function "Fillbackwards" is doing exactly what i want it to do for each group. However, when i use apply to use this function on each group, it returns an empty dataframe. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Thanks

Edited to clarify I want to fill na by growing the series backwards using another series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[np.nan, np.nan, 6, 6.7, np.nan, 5, 9, 10], 
                   'Y':[5.4, 5.7, 5.5, 6.1, 2.1, 1.5, 5.1, 2.1,],
                   'G': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']})


def Fillbackwards(DB, Sname, Growthrate):
    first_non_nan = DB[Sname].isnull().idxmin()
    while first_non_nan-DB.index[0] > 0:
        # Note the index of the group within the dataframe does not start at 0 as it's part of a larger frame - DB.index[0] restarts from zero
        DB.loc[first_non_nan-1-DB.index[0], Sname] = DB.loc[first_non_nan-DB.index[0], Sname]/(DB.loc[first_non_nan-DB.index[0], Growthrate]/100+1)
        first_non_nan -= 1

df = df.groupby('G').apply(lambda x: Fillbackwards(x, 'X', 'Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to fill the NaN values in X with the values in Y?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[np.nan, np.nan, 6, 6.7, np.nan, 5, 9, 10], 
                   'Y':[5.4, 5.7, 5.5, 6.1, 2.1, 1.5, 5.1, 2.1,],
                   'G': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']})

df['X'] = df['X'].fillna(df['Y'])
```

pandas has a built in way of handling this

Comment: Sorry I have clarified original post. I am trying to fill nan in X by growing it backwards using the growth rate Y

Answer (score 0):

I have realized my mistake: i did not have a "return" at the end of my function, so it returned null for each group.

Also, I have tweaked some of the above code in terms of indexing so it works correctly now.

Anyway: here is some code that lets you fill in missing values of series "X" by "growing it backwards" using growth rates in series "Y" separately for each group in "G":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[np.nan, np.nan, 6, 6.7, np.nan, 5, 9, 10], 
                   'Y':[5.4, 5.7, 5.5, 6.1, 2.1, 1.5, 5.1, 2.1,],
                   'G': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']})


def Fillbackwards(DB, Sname, Growthrate):
    first_non_nan = DB[Sname].isnull().idxmin()
    while first_non_nan > DB.index[0]:
        # Note the index of the group within the dataframe does not start at 0 as it's part of a larger frame - DB.index[0] restarts from zero
        DB.loc[first_non_nan-1, Sname] = DB.loc[first_non_nan, Sname]/(DB.loc[first_non_nan, Growthrate]/100+1)
        first_non_nan -= 1
    return DB

df = df.groupby('G').apply(lambda x: Fillbackwards(x, 'X', 'Y'))

check = df
```